# Can almost determine subnet membership given CIDR notation, but getting unexpected results

Tags: c, linux, networking

First off, looking at my code it seems like I should have it but smaller subnet masks seem to ALWAYS return true:

```
[root@hypervisor test]# ./test "99.99.99.99/8" 25.25.25.25

The given address is in the given cidr address
[root@hypervisor test]# ./test "99.99.99.99/16" 25.25.25.25

The given address is not in the given cidr address
[root@hypervisor test]# ./test "99.99.99.99/24" 25.25.25.25

The given address is not in the given cidr address
```

Obviously, the last two checks are ideal. Not getting unexpected negatives, just false positives. It also seems to fail only if I specify a subnet mask below ten:

```
[root@hypervisor test]# ./test "99.99.99.99/9" 25.25.25.25

The given address is in the given cidr address
[root@hypervisor test]# ./test "99.99.99.99/10" 25.25.25.25

The given address is not in the given cidr address
[root@hypervisor test]#
```

This is the function I've defined to do the work (rest of program is essentially if/else on return code, one on "given IP is in subnet" zero on "given IP is outside the subnet"):

```
int inSubnet(const char *cidrNotation, const char *needleAddress){

        char subnetDesignation[25], strPad[25];
        unsigned short int maskSize;
        unsigned int startOfCidr=strlen(cidrNotation)-3;
        unsigned long int subnetMask=0, givenIP, subnetAddress;
        unsigned short int iter=0;

        /* BEGIN sanitization of arguments */
          // If they gave real CIDR clip it off the end and save it.
        if (strstr(cidrNotation, "/")){

          strcpy(strPad, cidrNotation);
          maskSize=atoi( (strPad+startOfCidr+1) );
          *(strPad+startOfCidr) = '\0';
          strcpy(subnetDesignation, strPad);

          // Otherwise assume 32-bit mask (effectively equates two specific addys)
        } else {
          strcpy(subnetDesignation, cidrNotation);
          maskSize=32;
        } /* END SANITIZATION */

          // Generate subnet mask in network byte order
        for (iter=1; iter<maskSize; iter++){
                subnetMask=subnetMask<<1; // move mask right by one, fill LSB with zero
                subnetMask++; // flip the one bit on
        }

          // Get subnetDesignation into binary form and
        inet_pton(AF_INET, subnetDesignation, &subnetAddress);
        subnetAddress=subnetAddress & subnetMask; // Ensure it matches the subnet's prefix no matter how it was given

        inet_pton(AF_INET, needleAddress, &givenIP);

          // Since all non-subnet bits are flipped, the result of an AND should be identical to the subnet address.
        if ( (givenIP & subnetAddress) == subnetAddress)
                return 1;
        else
                return 0;

}
```

It seems like I'm incredibly close to getting this part of the project finished, I've just made some sort of oversight that I'm just missing somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can safely assume that the netmask always occupies three characters at the end of the string:

```
unsigned int startOfCidr=strlen(cidrNotation)-3;
```

When you have a `/8` mask, for example, you only use two characters to specify it. (This is probably also why it works for everything >= 10.) Try searching for a `/` character instead and parsing the netmask starting there.

Comment: Holy crap, I don't know how that one escaped me. Give me a minute to test but I'm almost positive that you're going to be correct.

Comment: I haven't updated my code yet but passing a `/08` subnet mask instead of just `/8` causes it to work as expected.

Comment: fwiw, replacing the literal pointer math with `strchr` output fixed the problem.